# How to get text format of message without filling up fields

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have got my protobuf [GeneratedMessage](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage)(only castable to this base) and I would like to get the text format(parsable by [TextFormat](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/TextFormat) class) including all fields of this message.

I see only two ways:

- by reflection find all setters and put in some values, then use TextFormat
- get list of fields(from api) and recreate this format

Neither of them is good, so my question is: is there any better way? If not which of these you find better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>If you have a `GeneratedMessage`, you may simply pass it into any of `TextFormat`'s print methods. `GeneratedMessage` implements the `MessageOrBuilder` interface which these methods want.</s>

EDIT: I see, your problem is that you want it to actually print all the fields, and TextFormat only prints fields that have been filled in.

You will have to fill in the fields with dummy data. This is actually pretty easy, though:

```
Message fillAllFields(Message prototype) {
  Message.Builder builder = prototype.newBuilderForType();
  for (FieldDescriptor field: builder.getDescriptorForType().getFields()) {
    builder.setField(field, prototype.getField(field));
  }
  return builder.build();
}
```

The trick here is that we're calling `setField()` for every defined field, not just the ones that are set in `prototype`. For the ones that aren't set there, `prototype.getField()` will return the default value, but we're still explicitly setting the field to that value, so it will now show up in text format. Note that this actually creates a *different* message from the original -- setting a field to its default value is detectably different from leaving the field unset.

Comment: But if none of the fields is set i just get empty string

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood the question. I'll answer again.

Comment: I will have to check if it works without defaults defined in .proto, but thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: I have problem with encapsulated messages. Is it possible to get Builder from Type?

Comment: @Krever Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean with your last comment.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it myself. getBuilderForField() was a key.